# Wordpress Programmatic Editing HTTP POST

Tags: java, wordpress, http, post, edit

I'm attempting to automate some Wordpress changes using HTTP requests in Java.
However, it seems as usual Wordpress managed to over-complicate things.

Why does it seem nearly impossible to POST www.mysite.com/wp-admin/post.php with my wordpress login cookies, and the data post=123&action=edit&content=NewContent

?

How come this isn't possible? Are they seriously stupid enough to be re-creating the whole post for each edit with post-new.php? (which it seems like they're doing based on the huge mess found in the headers)

I'm new to content management systems but I can't believe how horrible the frameworks seem.

I'm probably forced to use XMLRPC for my purpose which I guess is alright but I'd still like to know if I can do raw HTTP requests alternatively, and if not; why not.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do raw HTTP request manipuilation with tha Java Servlet API http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet, http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Servlets/Fundamentals/servlets.html

Comment: I don't see how a Servlet would help me edit blog page content. If I was going to edit the server I might as well just do database queries with PHP.

Comment: You wanted a way to deal with raw HTTP requests in java right? Servlets can do that.

Comment: I wanted a way to send an HTTP request that would change the content on my blog post. Which, ideally, would be something like www.site.com/wp-admin/post.php?&post=[ID of the post I'm targetting]&action=edit&content=[the new content for my targeted post] however to my surprise Wordpress(the content management system I'm working with) made it much more complicating than this.

Comment: All good, I ended up using XMLRPC using the wp.editPost function which worked out just fine(for anybody who needs to know, the 'struct' parameter is just a double-string HashMap, name and value).

I don't think raw HTTP requests are very common in the industry anyways.. lol

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why you would want that. But one thing that make you cannot edit post via HTTP request is because all the data is submitted via $_POST not $_GET. So unless you make some changes in the wp-admin/post.php and any files related to it, it will be possible.

IMHO, it's not a simple thing to be made complicated, it's just simple thing to be made secure.

Comment: You don't have any idea what I'm trying to do. $_POST and $_GET are PHP structs used after the HTTP request is made. I'm not coding in PHP, I'm creating a desktop-application in Java which is parsing XML documents and uploading them to a Wordpress site.